# start jar with Jline using Process and redirected stdin,stdout,stderr

Tags: java, c#, console, pipe, jline

I have the following problem. I'm trying to make a wrapper for interacting with the Microchip mdb debugger. Which is actually a java application. When trying to redirect stdin and stdout, it throws an error:

```
>?????? 03, 2023 4:19:47 PM org.jline.utils.Log logr
WARNING: Unable to create a system terminal, creating a dumb terminal (enable debug logging for more information)
```

I understand that the problem is that jline is waiting for something from the terminal for its logging and does not receive it, since we redirected stdin and stdout.
If I remove the stdin/stdout redirection, then have started child console window with the debugger launched and prompt. So what could i do to solve that?

There is my code. (I simplify it just a little using string constants instead of getting them programmatically)

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var mplabx_dir = @"C:\PROGRA~1\MICROC~1\MPLABX\v6.15\MPLAB_~1";
    var mdb_jar = @$"{mplabx_dir}\lib\mdb.jar";
    var jdk_home = @$"C:\Program Files\Microchip\MPLABX\v6.15\sys\java\zulu8.64.0.19-ca-fx-jre8.0.345-win_x64\bin\java.exe";
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    
    // I've tried to execute it through cmd.exe with the same result
    // startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";  
    // startInfo.ArgumentList.Clear();
    // startInfo.ArgumentList.Add("/C");
    // startInfo.ArgumentList.Add(jdk_home);
    
    startInfo.FileName = jdk_home;
    startInfo.ArgumentList.Clear();
    
    startInfo.ArgumentList.Add("-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8");
    startInfo.ArgumentList.Add("-jar");
    startInfo.ArgumentList.Add($"{mdb_jar}");
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    startInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
    startInfo.StandardInputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
    startInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
    
    commandsToSend = new List<string>();
    commandsToSend.Add("help");
    commandsToSend.Add("quit");
    commandsToSend.Add("");
    
    using (Process mdb = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
        int cmd_idx = 0;
        string from_mdb;
        var ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        while (mdb.Responding)
        {
            from_mdb = ReadLineNb(mdb.StandardOutput);
            from_mdb += ReadLineNb(mdb.StandardError);
            if (from_mdb != "")
                Console.Write(from_mdb);
    
            var currTicks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            if((currTicks - ticks) >= 500)
            {
                ticks = currTicks;
                var to_mdb = commandsToSend[cmd_idx++];
                Console.Write(to_mdb);
                mdb.StandardInput.WriteLine(commandsToSend[cmd_idx++]);
            }
        }
    }
}

static string ReadLineNb(TextReader stream)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    while (stream.Peek() > 0)
    {
        result.Append((char)stream.Read());
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Heh, after I posted this question, I thought about it. So, since JLine is trying to do something with log, it should be around stderr. Then I exclude the stderr redirection and get the jar terminal output.  
This does not solve the problems with the interception of stderr, but firstly it gives me the opportunity to continue my work, so far without it. And secondly, maybe stdin|out, without stderr will be enough for someone other.